# GA4 report in Looker Studio does show way too low numbers for users

Tags: looker-studio, google-analytics-4

I just connected GA4 to Looker Studio to start building a report. The first table for users by Default Channel Group is showing weird numbers - in Looker Studio are thousands missing.
Does anyone have an idea, how this huge discrepancy can appear? There is nothing in the report, yet, that might cause it - no filters, no merging of data sources.

Thanks so much, Eva
Screenshot of GA4 and Looker Studio for data conmparison[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check your time periods on the table, Looker studio defaults to 28 days on most of its graphs for the GA4 connector